# How to mock JSONP requests in Cypress tests?

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

For testing my component with google autocomplete I need to mock JSONP requests.
I use `cy.intercept()` but JSONP responses as usual contain function name to call and it's never called using `cy.intercept()` (it just substitutes real request)

There is a way to mock them by substituting whole `window.google` object with your own. But I don't want to go this way (and can't actually because cypress has it's own window and it never contains google object in my tests)

JSONP are requests technology which inserts script with callback function with response result as an argument into your page.

Comment: _"but JSONP responses as usual contain function name to call and it's never called using cy.intercept() (it just substitutes real request)"_ But... that's exactly what you are trying to do, no? `cy.intercept` allows you to [stub a response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Stubbing-a-response). If you stub it with a string like `theCallback({"some": "data"});`, it should run as expected. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The thing is that I want these callbacks (responses) to run somehow. Insert them as scripts during test run or somehow else.

Comment: Something does not make sense here. Your question's title states "How to mock JSONP requests". That is a way to do it. And now, you are saying that no code in your component/application actually makes a JSONP request (inserts the script in the page), and that you should do it manually with Cypress? In this case, maybe it would be easier to just skip the JSONP part, and directly call the callback with some data using [cy.window](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window#No-Args)?

Comment: When you just mock HTTP request to the same URL, it's callback is not called, so it's why it's not completely mocks JSONP request. cy.window doesn't have the callback in the scope btw as well as google. I would try to just substitude google library function in window rather than do this ```eval(`/**/${callback} && ${callback}(${response})`)```

Please provide an example how you did that, if you did.